# The AM2302 Temp/Humidity Sensor return none value in Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: pi-3

I am using the AM2302 Temp/Humidity Sensor.
I start with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install git python-dev
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT.git
cd Adafruit_Python_DHT/
sudo python setup.py install
```

and I connected the sensor:

1. "-" to GND (pin 6)
2. "+" to 3V3 (pin 1)
3. "S" (signal) to GPIO4 (pin 7)

[image]

I run  the following code :

```
import os
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import json

while True:
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
    msg = json.JSONEncoder().encode({'tem' : round(t,3),'hum' : round(h,3)})
    print msg
    time.sleep(5)
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tem_hum.py", line 9, in <module>
    msg = json.JSONEncoder().encode({'tem' : round(t,3),'hum' : round(h,3)})
TypeError: a float is required
```

which means there is no data it just returns none.

I already  tried these in the below links:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/issues/63
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/issues/73
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/issues/44

Any suggestion to make it read both Temp/Humidity.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you get if you print(h,t) after 'read_retry'?

Comment: only (none,none)

Comment: Example suggests setting sensor=Adafruit_DHT.AM2302 and passing sensor into read_entry   https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/examples/simpletest.py

Comment: @CoderMike The same result.

Comment: Add a photo of your wiring.

Comment: If you change directory to the examples folder, what does 'sudo ./AdafruitDHT.py 2302 4' do?

Comment: It shows this message `Failed to get reading. Try again!`

Comment: Have you enabled the 1-wire interface in raspberry pi configuration?

Comment: Yes, and I tried and it gives the same result.

Comment: Update your question with all this info.

Comment: The 1-wire interface `MUST NOT` be enabled with the default GPIO 4 if you are using the AM2302 on GPIO 4.

Comment: @joan Actually, I tried to apply some answer in GitHub and my `sudo rpi-update 52241088c1da59a359110d39c1875cda56496764`
`sudo reboot` and right now the raspberry pi doesn't connect at all.

Comment: Your problem is unlikely to be due to software (provided you followed the instructions in your question and did not install anything else). Your code works on my Pi3B+ with a DHT11. (I normally use code written by @joan) Your wiring differs from mine (but there is no standard for sensors). You should check actual connections (and DO NOT install unsupported "fixes").

Comment: @Milliways Do you  use the same  `"-" to GND (pin 6)`
`"+" to 3V3 (pin 1)`
`"S" (signal) to GPIO4 (pin 7)`

Comment: I use Gnd on pin 9 but this makes no difference. Some DHT modules lack pullup - but there is no consistency in connections or labelling of modules. It is easy to verify presence of a resistor by inspection or with a multimeter.

Comment: I will try it. I'm trying to use minitools to copy partition and I hope it will works.

Comment: I changed the sensor and it works.