# Raspberry pi doesn't connect at all after I did reboot

Tags: pi-3b+

I have Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and I tried to apply some answer in GitHub for a problem that I faced before.
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/issues/63

The problem is that when I run these commends

```
sudo rpi-update 52241088c1da59a359110d39c1875cda56496764
sudo reboot
```

My raspberry pi doesn't connect at all and only red light turn on and off. I tried to use `TTL-to-USB   cable`.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The AM2302 Temp/Humidity Sensor return none value in Raspberry Pi 3 B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92696/the-am2302-temp-humidity-sensor-return-none-value-in-raspberry-pi-3-b)

Comment: Actually, this is my question and the problem when I tried to solve it  my raspberry pi doesn't connect at all and only red light turn on and off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

You COULD try rebooting to a root shell and can repair most such problems on the Pi.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
   read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then edit files or restore kernel/bootcode.

Comment: Sorry, I can't connect the raspberry pi and I'm using win10. So, where should I run this commend?

Comment: You have broken Raspbian by running unsupported programs. Restore from your backup or re-install. There are lots of tutorials running DHT sensors on the Pi which don't involve all the questionable things Adafruit suggests.

Comment: There a lot of work there and I don't have any backup. If I copy the folders of the module and Install the same OS, do you think it will be working again?

Comment: If you can't boot the Pi your only option is to re-install - you could use a fresh SD Card. You COULD try rebooting to a root shell as in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92711/8697 but this needs direct connection

Comment: @i_th Or put Raspbian on a fresh SD card and use a USB SD card reader to get important stuff off the problem card.

Comment: I already use a new SD card and install a new raspberry pi. I will try to use Linux because the only thing that is shown in win10 is the boot and it is very small.

Comment: @Milliways  add the two of your last comments to the answer and I will approved.  I couldn't find any other solution.